# How to fix external drive in Linux the way Windows does automatically

Tags: mount, partition, windows, ntfs, external-hdd

I have unplugged an older 500 GB HD NTFS external drive without unmounting it first and then it couldn't be mounted in Linux. I have tried on different machines but the same error occurred. I was thinking to apply a "repair" procedure with the partition manager but before that I gave it a try on a Windows machine. It gave some error but then the files were accessed. It could be detached/unmounted and then it was fine in Linux too.

I guess Windows has automatically fixed the error related to the drive not being properly unmounted/disconnected, given Windows might have native better integration/interaction with the NTFS format.

I remember I had a similar problem with usb-stick drives on Mac: when the drive was not properly disconnected on Mac or Linux, it kept working on Linux but not on Mac, I had to re-plug and disconnect properly in Linux in orded to make it accessible on Mac. But this is the first time I have a drive better accessed by other system than Linux.

I might not have a Windows machine at hand when this happens again. Is there a simple way to get the same result - an easy fix like that - in Linux?

Comment: Using a native Linux FS is an easy fix.

Comment: @roaima - Athough I personally only use Linux, I have a few external drives  that are supposed to be used on Windows as well as Mac (and not just by me).

Comment: `fsck` can handle NTFS, usually it is just a matter of resetting the dirty bit and should not take much time.

Comment: @FelixJN - it happened again (this time just because I suspended with the drive connected, which seems like a bug), and `fsck` found no errors, but the drive remained unmountable (until I scanned and fixed errors with a XP VM).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy fix? Don't use NTFS, but instead use a Linux-native filesystem. Useful fix? No, none.

I see [in a comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/748595/how-to-fix-external-drive-in-linux-the-way-windows-does-automatically?noredirect=1#comment1424083_748595) that you "*have a few external drives that are supposed to be used on Windows as well as Mac*". On that basis you will presumably want to continue using NTFS, and therefore you will need to keep that Windows box around to fix the occasional errors you'll get using that filesystem on non-Windows systems.

If the causal trigger is that you forgot to unmount the filesystem before unplugging the external drive then maybe configuring an automounter with a short mount lifetime might be beneficial.

Comment: I guess what I meant was: can something like Wine and Playonlinux and tools inside those be used to fix a ntfs drive or partition on a such drive the way Windows does it?

Comment: @cipricus sorry, no idea

Comment: Anyway: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/757732/can-wine-and-or-playonlinux-be-used-to-fix-ntfs-errors-the-way-windows-does

Comment: I get a similar error again (and I have no Windows around) because I have closed the lid of the laptop with a movie playing (paused) from an external drive.

Comment: I just wanted to point out that the  error can happen even without removing the disk. I've just closed the lid :) Maybe k/Ubuntu bug?

Comment: @cipricus so, (a) you were using the filesystem, (b) you closed the lid so the system suspended itself, (c) you reopened the lid and the system continued, (d) instead of continuing as expected you found that the filesystem was corrupt? That's definitely a bug

Comment: That's exactly what happened. Thanks.

Comment: Any idea whether there are differences between Windows versions as to their method and swiftness of fixing this? — I remember that plunging the drive in a Windows 10 would prompt for fixing errors, and fixing took a few secs. Sometimes just accessing in Windows with no errors reported would be enough for the drive to become ok in Linux. But just now with a VM(VB) XP, WinXP was accessing the drive just fine (Linux didn't), so no automatic fixing took place and I had to run repair disk option in WinXP VM, which took *a lot* of time. It worked though.

Comment: @cipricus this [fault description and workaround](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=253584) appears to match your symptoms