# Can Wine and/or Playonlinux be used to fix ntfs errors the way Windows does?

Tags: windows, usb-drive, wine, ntfs, playonlinux

Very often, when a ntfs external drive cannot be mounted in Linux because of some more or less obscure motive, simply plugging it onto Windows fixes it, even without running the tool to scan and fix errors.

I often get those errors because I have many such external drives full of stuff around that I often use (please don't ask me to avoid ntfs: I do when I can). This has become my main reason for having a Window system installed somewhere.

But I wonder: could Wine/Playlinux be used for the same purpose somehow?

Couldn't that repair tool be installed in Wine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that's impossible. Wine does not try to emulate the Windows volume subsystem, so you can't do anything that expects a Windows volume.

[Source.](https://forum.winehq.org/viewtopic.php?p=71853&sid=1e9c844f4128897a7656b61a86ef1d7d#p71853)

You can, however, just run a Windows live system in a VM, and use the damaged filesystem as one of the VM's raw storage devices.

Comment: Any idea whether there are differences between Windows versions as to their method and swiftness of fixing this? — I remember that plunging the drive in a Windows 10 would prompt for fixing errors, and fixing took a few secs. Sometimes just accessing in Windows with no errors reported would be enough for the drive to become ok in Linux. But recently with a VM(VB) XP, WinXP was accessing the drive just fine (Linux didn't), so no automatic fixing took place and I had to run repair disk option in WinXP VM, which took *a lot* of time. Would Win 7 be faster? 10?

Comment: I can't really imagine them being much faster; disk checking is primarily IO bounded, so the speed depends on a) the speed of the actual storage and b) the speed of the drive emulation in your virtualizer, and c) the speed of how the physical hardware is interfaced into your VM. Maybe there's room for improvement there!

Comment: I have this experience with newer Windows that it says the drive has problems and needs to be fixed, although *it is accessible in Windows*, but if I dismiss the fixing still some very fast correction takes place by the mere access, so that it then works in Linux. XP doesn't give any message for a drive that it can access I guess, and doesn't do that fast check and/or fix so the longer procedure is needed anyway for my scenario. - But I may be wrong!

Comment: That might have to do with newer on-disk formats of NTFS; but you cannot use an on-disk format introduced with for example Win10 on a Win XP machine, it couldn't read that. And: when checking a disk of the old format, win10 wouldn't be significantly faster – it still has to do the exact same things that XP had to do.